# Fullcalendar individual resource slotDuration

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Using FullCalendar.io does anyone know if it's possible to customise the slotDuration based on the resource (similar to businessHours)? I'm using a "resourceTimeGridDay" with multiple resources (one per vertical column).  My issue is some resources require 15 minutes, others 30 minutes. I've searched for hours and am amazed I find nothing related.

Any brilliant ideas?

EDITED:
Ok, if this isn't possible, how can I restrict the selections (where the user selects an empty space in the timetable).
eg.  The calendar displays 15 minute durations, column A all at 15 no worries.  Column B however needs a 60 minute duration, starting on the hour only.  So if a user selects 4:15PM in column B I actually need from 4PM to 5PM to be selected.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: No you can't do that unfortunately. Just use the smallest duration you require, and you have to apply it across the whole calendar. Does that cause a specific problem? Maybe a workaround could be applied if you explain what the difficulties are with that approach.

Comment: Re your edit: handle selectAllow (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow) and use the info provided to decide whether the selection's time period is large enough, for the resource where the selection is being made.

Comment: Thanks ADyson! I think that'll do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that unfortunately. You must just use the smallest duration you require, and you have to apply it across the whole calendar.

To restrict the selection length on a per-resource basis, one approach would be to handle selectAllow (fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow) and use the info provided to decide whether the selection's time period is large enough, for the resource where the selection is being made.